# Why text2.Text = "message" is not working in my code?

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin.android

Why text2.Text = "message" is not working in my code ?
I want to use it in a function as per the below source code.
I developed in Visual Stduio with Mono for android in C#.

The Source code:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace ChatClient_Android
{
[Activity(Label = "ChatClient_Android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainChat : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
        EditText text2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.text2);
     }
     
   private void  recieved()
   {
    text2.Text = "mesage";   // The text2 does not existe in this context 

    }
 }
```

}

Comment: text2 is out of scope. You need to declare it above the method if you wish to reuse it in another.

Try something like:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`EditText text2` is declared not global but to the method. Put `EditText text2;` in the class.

Should be like this :

```
public class MainChat : Activity
{
    EditText text2; // <----- HERE
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        text2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.text2);
     }

   private void  recieved()
   {
    text2.Text = "mesage";   

    }
 }
```

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if this one is working for you.

Answer (score 2):

`text2` is defined inside `OnCreate`, therefore `received` knows nothing about it.

You need to define text2 as a class field, like this:

```
public class MainChat : Activity
{
    private EditText text2;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        // Get our button from the layout resource,
        // and attach an event to it
         text2 = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.text2);
     }

   private void  recieved()
   {
    text2.Text = "mesage";   // The text2 does not existe in this context 

    }
 }
```